# GPS based application not running under lock screen in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have developed a windows phone application and it works fine when it is open and running actively.
It tracks the user movements on the map and shows the position moves with push pins.

Now I want to ensure that the same application runs even the phone is locked when this app was open.
I have added the below code for it to work under lock screen. After this when I verified the app I realized it is not running when the application is locked.

Is there any other change I need to make to get this work under lock screen.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void initiliazesettings()
{
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = 
       IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have your app running under lock screen on Windows Phone 7.0/7.1/8.0, you need to set ApplicationIdleDetectionMode, not UserIdleDetectionMode. See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Changingtheappidledetectionmode).

Answer (score 1):

Supossing you placed the method in the right place, that code only keeps the screen on, but doesn't make your app run in background when the lock screen is activated. Windows Phone 7 apps cannot run in background, they get tombstoned.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 8 this is possible - [see the sample here from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

However for Windows Phone 7/7.1 you can't do this.

You can prevent the screen from locking due to the user not interacting with it (as your code shows). However if you manually lock the screen the app will still be made dormant or tombstoned and your location code won't run.

Your only other option is to use a scheduled background task to read the location of the phone, but bear in mind that this is far from real time data (it is a cached location and you only run once every 30 minutes in the best case scenario).

Comment: Oh..I just realized that the code I have written will only ensure the screen is not locked by setting the idledetectionmode to disabled.Thanks for the reply.